# Wordpress: custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have posts with custom field(name: link; value: www.google.com)
If I use on page with posts this construction:

```
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true) ) { ?>
<?php $link=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true); ?>
<a href="http://<?php echo $link; ?>"><img src="image.png">
<?php } else {} ?>
```

I have fantom links in different places of page. What is wrong?

Comment: You aren't closing your <a> tag. Put a `</a>` after the `<img>` :)

Comment: Many thanks!!! I went on vacation...